# div auto responsive to text inside

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV inside another. One of those has "plain text" and what I want to do is to make its width automatic with a maximum with possible.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="artigo_nome"> <!-- here is the part that I need help -->
    <p>
        Computador Apple Imac 27P I5 3.5Ghz/8Gb/1Tb Md096Po/A
    </p>
</div>
<div class="artigo_definicoes round_corner">
    <div class="separador_artigo_imagem">
        <img src="img/artigos/fones.png" class="imagem_artigo" alt="artigo"/>
    </div>
    <div class="artigo_info">
       Computador Apple Imac 27P I5 3.5Ghz/8Gb/1Tb Md096Po/A<br />
       <span class="ler_mais">ver mais</span><br />
       <span class="comparar">adicionar para comprar</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.categoria_lista_artigos .artigo_nome{
    color:#6e6e6e;
    width:234px;
    height:34px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    border-left:2px #aeaeae solid;
    border-right:2px #aeaeae solid;
    border-bottom:1px #aeaeae solid;
    /*background-color:#E6E6E6;*/
    position:relative;
    font-weight: 600;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -3px 5px #e2e2e2;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px -3px 5px #e2e2e2;
    box-shadow:         0px -3px 5px #e2e2e2;
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #cfcfcf 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#cfcfcf)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#cfcfcf 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#cfcfcf 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#cfcfcf 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#cfcfcf 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#cfcfcf',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.categoria_lista_artigos .artigo_nome div {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 4px 13px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:13px;
}
```

If you need anything more, just say.

Comment: by the way for which div are you trying to set the size?

Comment: I've tried, but in that case, I can't set a max width, and when I use max-width, it stays always on that width, not turning responsive

Comment: @UmangMehta to ".artigo_nome"

Comment: There is an extra `</div>` on line 6, i'm not sure it's intended.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is a shrink-to-fit width for your text line.

You can simplify your HTML as follows:

```
<div class="artigo_nome">
Computador Apple Imac 27P I5 3.5Ghz/8Gb/1Tb Md096Po/A
</div>
```

and apply the following CSS rules:

```
.artigo_nome {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 250px;
    padding: 10px;
    word-break: break-all; /* optional */
}
```

which gives the following result: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/vVhWR/

The `inline-block` will give you a shrink-to-fit width up to the specified `max-width` value.

If you want to be able to wrap long words, add the `word-break` property.

**Note:** I left out the border/shadow/background styling for simplicity, but you can easily add them back in.

Comment: If you set the max width, the text may wrap on to a second line, but that may be okay.

Comment: Questions: (1) Do you want the text line to be on a single line if at all possible? (2) Do you want the line to start wrapping after a max width? (3) If you have very short text, do you want the box to shrink-to-fit the text if it is less than max width?

Comment: 1) no, i don't need it to be in single line, I just want it to have max width of X px. 2) yes 3) yes